# ReferenceError: module is not defined when compiling kotlin to JS Browser

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I'm building a multi-platform Kotlin project. The back-end must compile to both `JS  Browser` and `JVM`. I have 2 front-ends for the 2 platforms. The problem is when I try to run the code. I can build it with `gradle` no problem, but in the browser I'm getting a `ReferenceError: module is not defined` on line `venus.js:23643:1`. I'm not sure what the problem is. I've added some new dependencies to the project ([`korio`](https://korlibs.soywiz.com/korio/) and [`klogger`](https://korlibs.soywiz.com/klogger/)), but I made sure I only use things that are available on both platforms (I only use [WebSockets](https://korlibs.soywiz.com/korio/#websocket-client) and [Base64](https://korlibs.soywiz.com/korio/#base64) from the `korio`, as I understand `WebSockets` are supported on all platforms as mentioned [here](https://github.com/korlibs/korio#websocketclient)). I am stuck on this problem for days now. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
group 'venus'
version '0.1.0'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.70'
    ext.dokka_version = '0.10.1'
    ext.ktlint_version = '0.27.0'
    ext.korioVersion = "1.11.10"
    ext.kloggerVersion = "1.10.1"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-dce-js'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-js'

runDceKotlinJs.keep 'venus.Driver.run', 'venusbackend.assembler.Linter', 'venus.api.API', "kotlin.Number"

runDceKotlinJs.dceOptions.devMode = true
runDceTestKotlinJs.dceOptions.devMode = true

configurations {
    ktlint
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url("https://dl.bintray.com/korlibs/korlibs") }
}

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
    kotlinOptions.sourceMapEmbedSources = "always"
    // remaining configuration options
    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
}

task ktlint(type: JavaExec) {
    description = "Check Kotlin code style."
    main = "com.github.shyiko.ktlint.Main"
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    args "--verbose", "src/**/*.kt"
}

check.dependsOn ktlint

task ktlintFormat(type: JavaExec) {
    description = "Fix Kotlin code style deviations."
    main = "com.github.shyiko.ktlint.Main"
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    args "-F", "src/**/*.kt"
}

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "doc"
}

dependencies {
    ktlint "com.github.shyiko:ktlint:$ktlint_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.soywiz.korlibs.korio:korio-js:$korioVersion"
    implementation "com.soywiz.korlibs.klogger:klogger-js:$kloggerVersion"
}
```

And [here](https://ufile.io/szo3acq3) is the `venus.js` file that was created.

For more context: [Here](https://github.com/ThaumicMekanism/venus) is the project I'm working on. I'm trying to add an external virtual memory and the communication with the memory should go through `WebSockets`.

Comment: On what branch can I reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm posting at this moment everything into a private GitLab server, so I can't show you my code and what I've done, but the maintainer of KorIO released a patch for my problem. I'm going to try that out and see how that goes. I also found out that KorIO has a dependency to requireJS (it wasn't in the documentation or anything). If the patch doesn't work I'll try to add that dependency to my project.

Comment: Ok, I've applied the patch from the KorIO developer and thta sorted out the ```require``` problem (I had this problem before, and now it's gone). I still have this with ```module is not defined``` problem though. I think you may be able to reproduce this problem on the ```js``` branch of the project, but you need to change the ```build.gradle``` as shown above.

Comment: I failed to build your project, but maybe it helps to change the module system to `commonjs` - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html

Comment: I finally managed to build it, but now I ran into yet another problem. It builds without any error and runs ok, but when I try to connect to the server via ```WebSocket``` I get an error and nothing gets sent to the server (I looked it up on ```Wireshark``` and I can't see the package going from client to server). I can send you an email with the complete code so that you can have a look. I've been stuck for days now trying to solve this problem

Comment: Here - https://ufile.io/outb4cu0 is the complete project (client) and here - https://ufile.io/usbs4gxz is the server (it's a virtual motherboard, you need to start it by running ```mother.exe```) and clicking on the "power on" button, then you can build the project and run it in the browser. To do that you need to build the venus project (```./gradlew clean build``` in the venus directory) and then run ```grunt dist``` and you'll find everything in the ```out``` directory

Comment: When I change the module system to ```commonjs``` I get the same ```Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined```